# My theme is automatically disabled!

Tags: theming, subsites

My Drupal website has a sub-domain. there is a  theme that is in the sub-domain folder. the `settings.php` in the sub-domain folder is same as the one that is in the `/default` folder so they both display the same web page. the problem is after a few hours this theme is automatically disabled and I have to enable it again.

why such thing happens?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you have 2 URL (www.ex.com and sub.ex.com) with the dir/ and files:

```
/sites

   all/

      themes/

      modules/ 

   www.ex.com/

      themes/

        your_theme/

   sub.ex.com/
```

and no "/sites/sites.php" in here? (read for ex "example.sites.php")

And selected in www.ex.com/admin/appearance for ex bartik as default
and for sub.ex.com/admin/appearance "the your_theme" as default (and clear cache)?

and each time, you need to go in sub.ex.com/admin/appearance in order to set "the your_theme" as default, with no error in logs?

Comment: `sites.php` is not in there. because the `www.ex.com` and the `www.ex.com` they both have the same `settings.php` so they both have same default theme (actually the same database). from what I found out during the update process the theme get disabled. so I disabled the `run cron` and  my theme didn't get disable at all. actually this solution is not good at all but I had out.